# NavigationLink in the Page TabView works with an error

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, tabview

Here is the code i am trying to reproduce.
The problem is that when you click on the link, the screen opens without animation and an error is generated in the console.
But if you go to another page Tab and go back, then everything works correctly.

```
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        //First Screen
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                Text("Hello Page 1")
            } label: {
                Text("Page 1")
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        .tag(1)

        //Second Screen
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                Text("Hello Page 2")
            } label: {
                Text("Page 2")
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        .tag(2)
    }
    .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
}
```

Comment: Here is error text:

2022-05-17 10:46:49.390317+0300 MyApp[30847:884875] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVVS_22_VariadicView_Children7ElementVS_24NavigationColumnModifier__: 0x7fa4d4b131a0>.

2022-05-17 10:46:53.083979+0300 MyApp[30847:884875] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_24NavigationColumnModifier__: 0x7fa4d4b0d7b0>.

Answer (score 1):

To correct this error you need to use individual structs in your `TabView`. In a real app, you would be doing this as a matter of course, and would not ever see this error. An example would be:

```
struct MyTabView: View {
    var body: some View {
            TabView {
                Content1()
                    .tag(1)

                Content2()
                    .tag(2)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}

struct Content1: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                Text("Hello Page 1")
            } label: {
                Text("Page 1")
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}

struct Content2: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                Text("Hello Page 2")
            } label: {
                Text("Page 2")
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}
```

`NavigationView` would go in each of these contained structs as they would be the top of the hierarchy for each tab.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the error still remains. Even in the code you gave, when run on an emulator or a real device, it gives the same error. It is important that it appears only if you do not initially move TabView, but immediately try to follow the NavLink. if you scroll through the tab, then on both screens the function works well.

Comment: This code did not show any error. I would start with a clean build and test it. You may have problems elsewhere. Also, try a different simulator.